# Concurrent users in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

I am looking to set up an Oracle APEX application on Oracle Express edition.  The user limit is 2. How is the number of concurrent users determined?

Comment: As Littlefoot suggests, this question isn't really relevant in a stateless, connection pooled environment. Why should there by a limit?

Answer (score 2):

> I am looking to set up an Oracle APEX application on Oracle Express edition.

That's fine.

---

> The user limit is 2.

OK; as far as I understood, 2 users will be using that application.

---

> How is the number of concurrent users determined?

Are you worried that those 2 users won't be able to use your application simultaneously? If so, no problem. **Many more** users will be able to do that.

As far as I can tell, there's no way to say who is *currently* using your application, but you can check who was logged in during the last, for example, 10 minutes. You'd run such a query (presuming that it is the only application in your workspace):

```
select apex_user, 
       to_char(last_view, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') last_view
from apex_workspace_log_summary_usr
where workspace = 'YOUR_WORKSPACE_NAME'
and apex_user <> 'nobody'
and last_view > sysdate - 10 / (24 * 60);  
                          ^^
                       -- last view was within the last 10 minutes
```

Or, check such a query: it'll show users who accessed your application within the last 10 minutes, and how many seconds passed since that.

```
select apex_user, 
       min(seconds_ago) min_sec_ago
  from apex_workspace_activity_log
 where workspace = 'YOUR_WORKSPACE_NAME'
   and application_id = YOUR_APPLICATION_ID
   and apex_user <> 'nobody' 
   and seconds_ago < 10 * 60
                  -- ^^ 10 minutes ago
group by apex_user;
```